# Blade comparison, DW4765 vs DW4701:

Tags: saw

What's the difference between [DW4765](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001M0GBOG) and [DW4701](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000224X2)?

[image: DW4765]

[image: DW4701]

Would the use cases be any different? They're both advertised for stone, granite, brick, and tile.

Comment: It probably doesn't really matter, but according to the images, the DW4765 has a lower max RPM than the DW4701. (13,300 vs 14,400)

Comment: The description for DW4765 states it's for a tile saw, while DW4701 says it's for a grinder. I'm not sure why those would not be interchangeable however, given that they seem to have the same arbor size and type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the DW4765 and DW4701 blades are listed by Dewalt as XP products.
More importantly is the difference in intended use.

The DW4765 is for use in a tile saw. This means it's designed for wet cutting where the temperature never gets very high because it is constantly water cooled. It is a little thinner and thus has a thin kerf.

The DW4701 is for use in an angle grinder. It is for dry cutting and thus can handle higher temperatures. This is achieved with the segments which allow better airflow for cooling. The cut will likely be by hand so the blade should be a little stiffer and thicker. This results in a wider kerf.

Comment: Great answer, bad marketing on the park on DW. The DW4765 should be marketed for wet saws only then.

Comment: Yeah, their marketing drives me crazy. You know the design engineers and manufacturing engineers and application/product engineers know this in their sleep but they couldn't bother to write it down for customers. And then they push it through big box stores like H*** D**** or L**** where no one on the floor has any clue!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with these, so I can't say if it's marketing fluff or a real difference, but the DW4765 is an "XP/Extended Performance" blade which is supposed to have (according to the product marketing) a 4x lifetime compared to non-XP blades.

So assuming this is true, then you're paying just over $8 more for a blade that will last much longer.  So (4 x 21.59) - $29.85  = $56.51 savings over the cost of buying 3 additional blades.

Comment: The DW4701 claims 350x over abrasive blades and the DW4765 claims 450x; sounds like marketing gimmicks to me...